# TYPO3 content fallback

Tags: typo3

What I try to do is to define a alternative language fallback for non translated content elements.

By default the language uid 0 is defined as fallback. I want to change this to language uid 1, which is englisch in my case.

I make the following language settings im my Typoscript Setup

```
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.sys_language_overlay = 1
config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback;1,0
config.language = de
config.locale_all =  de_DE.UTF8
```

What I expect is that the fallback for pages and content is englisch and not german.

What's wrong here?

Comment: How do you make sure that there is no German page, when German is UID 0 and must be existing before creating translated pages?

Answer (score 0):

As the name states ***content_fallback*** is meant to change the display of (tt_)content not pages. Take a look at the frontend localization guide to get a better overview of the different results of the sys_language_mode configurations:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FrontendLocalizationGuide/LocalizationModes/Index.html#best-practice-localization-mode

Answer (score 0):

For typo3 v11 have a look at:
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mst_contentfallback
Use strict mode and define the fallback language.
Lanuage 0 must be least fallback language.